# Confused over SQL statement for CASE WHEN inside INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert, case-when

I have the following SQL statement (that is intended for SQL Server):

```
INSERT INTO t1 (c1, c2) 
VALUES (1, CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(c2) FROM t1 AS maxV) IS NOT NULL THEN maxV+1 ELSE 1 END);
```

I get an error: "Invalid column name 'maxV'"

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `COALESCE`:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (c1, c2) 
SELECT 1, COALESCE(MAX(c2), 0) + 1
FROM t1
```

Comment: `COALESCE` better to use than `ISNULL`? (nice solution +1)

Comment: This method seems to be the only one that is short and works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
INSERT INTO t1 (c1, c2) 
VALUES (
    1, 
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT MAX(c2) FROM t1) IS NOT NULL 
        THEN (SELECT MAX(c2)+1 FROM t1)
        ELSE 1 
    END);
```

Comment: Thank you. Although, wouldn't it be redundant (speed wise) to do the same SELECT MAX(c2) two times?

Comment: I don't think you can re-use the column as you have tried, you're right it's not the best way to do it. My other answer and Mark's is a better way, I was just fixing your original query with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it...

```
INSERT INTO t1 (c1, c2) 
VALUES (1, ISNULL(SELECT MAX(c2) FROM t1, 0)+1);
```

Comment: This answer is also very good. I didn't know that I can use SELECT inside INSERT. Thank you!

Comment: I tried this method and it didn't work. Evidently you cannot so SELECT from within VALUES when doing INSERT INTO. It'd be nice if someone could confirm it?

Comment: You can, but you have to wrap the `SELECT` statement in parenthesis: `INSERT INTO t1 (c1, c2) VALUES (1, ISNULL((SELECT MAX(c2) FROM t1), 0) + 1);`